# how to update model is part of a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

My application uses backbone.js and requirejs, I have a "Questions module, that displays questions from database and its answers" and below are the structure of the module:

1. views/questions view
2. views/question item view
3. collection/questions collection
4. models/question model

everything is going ok with my app as i could retrieve all the data from the collection and render it to the page. earlier this week i was stacked with an issue when creating my rating system that consist of up and down buttons,

**what i need to do is to update the model when the user clicking on the up/ down button with the new value and re-render the item view again with the new value.**

I'll attach for you the code of the four pages mentioned above, everything on the codes below are working perfectly and i didn't include any functions or events that should handle the update procedure.

**Questions view**

```
// Filename: views/_activity_slider_inHeader
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'app/config',
'app/collections/questions',
'app/views/home_question_item',
'text!templates/questions_home.html',
'bootbox'
], function($, _, Backbone, Config, QuestionsCollection, SingleQuestionView, question_slider_template, bootbox) {
var ActivitySlider = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".content_container"),
    template: _.template(question_slider_template),
    initialize: function() {
        /*
         * initial script
         */
        var questionsCollection = new QuestionsCollection();
        this.collection = questionsCollection;
        questionsCollection.fetch({
            reset: true,
            error: function(model, xhr, options) {
                /*
                 * When triggering error:
                 *      1. If ther response is not valid json
                 *      2. There is error connecting to the server
                 */
                if (xhr['readyState'] === 1 | xhr['status'] === 404) {

                    /*
                     * the connection has not been made, user may be not connected to the internet
                     * @readyState The state of the request:
                     *             0 = UNSENT
                     *             1 = OPENED
                     *             2 = HEADERS_RECEIVED
                     *             3 = LOADING
                     *             4 = DONE
                     */
                    var msg = "pla pla",
                            title = "pla pla";

                    bootbox.dialog({
                        /*
                         * bootbox.dialog, bootbox.prompt, bootbox.confirm, bootbox.alert
                         * bootbox should have a callback used for the buttons
                         */
                        message: msg,
                        title: title,
                        buttons: {
                            main: {
                                label: "pla pla",
                                className: "",
                                callback: function() {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
                if (xhr['readyState'] === 4 & xhr['status'] === 200) {
                    /*
                     * Handling empty data
                     * connections to the server made successfully but seems to be there is no data returned by the server
                     */

                }
            }
        });
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
        this.renderList();
    },
    render: function(questions) {

        /*
         * Ilterate through all activities and start rendering item by item through the SingleActivityView
         */
        if (questions.size() === 0) {
            /*
             * there is no available activities
             * further use ..
             */

        } else {

            var i = 1;
            //there is activities available
            questions.each(function(question) {
                //create instance of the single item view
                var current = question.attributes,
                        singleQuestionView = new SingleQuestionView({
                    model: question,
                    collection: this.collection,
                    id: i
                });
                this.$el.append(singleQuestionView.render().el);

                i++;
            }, this);

        }

    },
    renderList: function() {
        /*
         * rendering the slider structure itself first
         */
        var data = {
            path: Config.baseUrl,
            _: _
        };
        this.$el.append(this.template(data));
    }
});

return ActivitySlider;

});
```

**Question item view**

```
/* Filename: views/home_question_item
* used to handle one row of the questions objects, merge the model data onto call list item
*/
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'app/config',
'text!templates/question_item_home.html',
'string',
'moment',
'moment_ar',
'jquerycookie',
'purl'
], function($, _, Backbone, Config, QuestionItemTemplate, S, moment, moment_ar) {
var url = $.url(),
    ActivityItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("li"),
    template: _.template(QuestionItemTemplate),
    initialize: function(){

    },
    render: function() {

        var model = this.model.attributes;

        var data = {
            path: Config.baseUrl,
            lang: url.segment(1),
            id: model['id'],
            date: model['date'],
            views: model['views'],
            author: model['author'],
            authorName: model['authorName'],
            question: model['question'],
            answer: model['answer'],
            rate: model['rate'],
            _ : _,
            S: S,
            moment: moment
        };

        $(".list_of_question").append(this.template(data));
        return this;
    },
    close: function(){
        console.log('destroyed');
        $(this.el).unbind();
        $(this.el).remove();            
    }
});
return ActivityItemView;
});
```

**Questions collection**

```
// Filename: collections/activities
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'app/config',
'app/models/question',    
'moment',
'purl'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Config, question, moment) {

var url = $.url(),
    ActivitiesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: question,
    url: Config.baseUrl + url.segment(1) + '/pull/questions'

});
return ActivitiesCollection;
});
```

**Questions model**

```
// Filename: models/activity
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'app/config',
'purl'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Config) {

var url = $.url(),
    ActivityModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: 'N/A'
    },
    urlRoot: Config.baseUrl + url.segment(1) + '/pull/questions/'

});
return ActivityModel;

});
```

Comment: But what have you tried? You need a function in the question view which is triggered when the user clicks the arrow. This function should update the question model with the new rate. And the  question item view should be listening to the change event of the model to re-render itself.

Comment: @Puigcerber here is the point, i need to know how & where to update the model itself with the new rate, then the listen for the model change would be easy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested the code but it should be something like this:

```
var ActivityItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("li"),
    template: _.template(QuestionItemTemplate),
    initialize: function(options){
        this.model = options.model;
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render, this); 
    },
    events : {
        'click #arrowUp' : 'increaseModelRating',
        'click #arrowDown' : 'decreaseModelRating',
    },
    render: function() {
        var data = { '...' };
        $(".list_of_question").append(this.template(data));
        return this;
    },
    increaseModelRating: function() {
        var currentRating = this.model.get('rating');
        this.model.set('rating', ++currentRating);
    },
    decreaseModelRating: function() {
        var currentRating = this.model.get('rating');
        this.model.set('rating', --currentRating);
    },  
    close: function() { '...' }
});
```

Comment: Great, think it would be closer now, now how could i save this changes to the database of that model only

Comment: Calling `this.model.save()` after setting the attribute.

Comment: i am tried this, but it didn't sent the new attribute of the model via PUT method, it sent the current attribute